# Unable to change the popviewcontrolleranimation

Tags: ios, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to change the `navigationController` push and pop animation like `presentModalView` and `dismissModalView` animation.

I am successfully change the push view animation by using the below code. For changing push animation is working fine. This code is shows the `view` from bottom to top animation(for push view).

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn];
transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:locationObj animated:NO];
```

But When I am trying to change the pop view animation by using the below code. I am unable to get the top to bottom animation(for pop view).

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

Please can some one help me.

Comment: What are you seeing? Your second transition is a push, not the type you are talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tested Code:**

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.4f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

//Pop Animation
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromBottom;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];


//Push Animation
//transition.type = kCATransitionMoveIn;
//transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromTop;
//[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToBePushed animated:NO];
```

Comment: Hey dude, i worked on sample app. code was updated, verify now. Tested.